# M2 - disappearing image after

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-images, image

once I tried to add image to product (and save it ofc) I got this error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452
>   Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`magento`.`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`, CONSTRAINT
>   `CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_VAL_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_ID` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`value_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity_med) in
>   /var/www/domain/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

Until this time If I add image to product at backend it save successfully and I am able to see it in backend and frontend.
However image is disappearing after few sec.

In exception.log I got this message:

> main.CRITICAL: Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException: The image
>   content is not valid. in
>   /var/www/domain/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php:470

and sometimes:

> main.WARNING: Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException: Cannot
>   gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for
>   /var/www/domain/pub/media/catalog/product/n/e/image_name.jpg
>   in
>   /var/www/domain/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:71

I checked values of `catalog_product_entity_media_galery` and `catalog_product_entity_media_galery_value` right after add image and save product -> everything was fine. But for while it just disappear.
Tried with few products and few different images.

It happened on production. Can not reproduce on Local and QA.

Magento 2.1.7
PHP 7.0.20

Comment: please redeploy..

Comment: So you think this is because of deploy?  Not sure what could go wrong?

Comment: worth a try....